# Prevent repeated values in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to prevent repeated values in textbox using javascript?
I'm having textbox in aspx form.And i've to split the textbox content using semicolon->";".And my task is to allow unique values with ; as like Value1;Value2;..Help me guys how to prevent repeated content in texbox? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#fileName").keyup(function(evt) {


             var txt = $("#fileName").val();
             var valueArray = txt.split(';');

             var valueSortArray = valueArray.sort();

             var duplicateValues = [];
             for (var i = 0; i < valueSortArray.length - 1; i++) {
                 if (valueSortArray[i + 1] == valueSortArray[i]) {
                     duplicateValues.push(valueSortArray[i]);
                 }
             }
             if (duplicateValues.length > 0)
                 $("#duplicate").html("These are the duplicate value " + duplicateValues);
             else
                 $("#duplicate").html("");



         });
     });
```

```css
#duplicate{
    color:red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="fileName" value="" id="fileName">
<div id="duplicate">
```